# Create a loop of bootstrap 4 card with given array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create the HTML like this picture. This css using bootstrap 4.3.1 and there are some card with embedded picture for each card

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ms8wU.png)

with the source code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>DOM Practice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-g5uSoOSBd7KkhAMlnQILrecXvzst9TdC09/VM+pjDTCM+1il8RHz5fKANTFFb+gQ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Mini Ecommerce</a>
            <form class="form-inline" id="formItem" action="#">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="keyword" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchItem">Search</button>
            </form>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>(0)</button>
        </nav>
        <div class="row" id="shop">
            <div id="keyBoard" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="msi.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="keyboard">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">MSI</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">MSI Keyboard</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Rp 300.000,00</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="keyBoard" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="logitek.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="keyboard">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">Logitek</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">Logitek Keyboard</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Rp 60.000,00</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="moUse" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="genius.jpeg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="mouse">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">Genius</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">Genius Mouse</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Rp 50.000,00</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">TAdd to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="moUse" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img src="jerry.jpg" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="mouse">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">Jerry</h5>
                        <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">Jerry Mouse</p>
                        <p class="card-text">Rp 30.000,00</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Add to cart</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

My questions : how to display that cards (bootstrap card) with a loop of javascript than input manually, if I'm add this array to the script :

```html
var items = [
            [ 'Logitek', 'Rp 60.000,00', 'Logitek Keyboard', 'logitek.jpeg'],
            [ 'MSI', 'Rp 300.000,00', 'MSI Keyboard', 'msi.jpeg'],
            [ 'Genius', 'Rp 50.000,00', 'Genius Mouse', 'genius.jpeg'],
            [ 'Jerry', 'Rp 30.000,00', 'Jerry Mouse', 'jerry.jpeg']
        ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `forEach` and [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
var items = [
  ['Logitek', 'Rp 60.000,00', 'Logitek Keyboard', 'logitek.jpeg'],
  ['MSI', 'Rp 300.000,00', 'MSI Keyboard', 'msi.jpeg'],
  ['Genius', 'Rp 50.000,00', 'Genius Mouse', 'genius.jpeg'],
  ['Jerry', 'Rp 30.000,00', 'Jerry Mouse', 'jerry.jpeg']
]

let content = '';

items.forEach(p => {
  content += `
    <div id="keyBoard" class="col-md-4 mt-2">
              <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <img src="${p[3]}" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="keyboard">
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title" id="itemName">${p[0]}</h5>
                      <p class="card-text" id="itemDesc">${p[2]}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">${p[1]}</p>
                      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="addCart">Add to cart</a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
  `
});

document.querySelector("#shop").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand">Mini Ecommerce</a>
    <form class="form-inline" id="formItem" action="#">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" id="keyword" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchItem">Search</button>
    </form>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="cart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>(0)</button>
  </nav>
  <div class="row" id="shop">
  </div>
</div>
```